# Como posso listar todos os diretorios utilizando FTP?

Tags: php, ftp

Já tentei com  [ftp_nlist()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ftp-nlist.php) e com [ftp_rawlist()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ftp-rawlist.php) mas o retorno é sempre um array vazio.

A questão de Acesso/Autenticação esta ok, só tentará ler uma lista se o mesmo
já estiver conectado com um usuário:

### Exemplo:

```
$dados = array('host' => 'localhost', 'usuario' => 'teste', 'senha' => '123456');

$conn = ftp_connect($dados['host']);

if (ftp_login($conn, $dados['usuario'], $dados['senha'])):
//   var_dump(ftp_nlist($conn, '.'));
   var_dump(ftp_rawlist($conn, '/'));
endif;
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o modo passivo:
ftp_pasv($conn, true);

Comment: Até tentei mas o meu problema a principio não é este o ftp_pasv é bom para quando você tem firewall mas o ftp que criei e na minha propria maquina

Comment: Outras funções ftp como o ftp_get funciona:
ftp_get($conn, 'arquivolocal.xyz', 'arquivoremoto.xyz',  FTP_ASCII, 0) 
?

Comment: Já verificou se tem permissão de listar no FTP?

Comment: sim, por que se eu fizer um ftp://usuario:senha@localhost eu consigo autenticar e visualizar todas as pastas, pedi para um colega meu acessar o meu ip e funcinou também

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu testei o seu código no meu servidor e funciona na perfeição
tanto o `ftp_nlist()` como o `ftp_rawlist()`

Esta a trabalhar localmente ou num host? 
se estiver alojado num host experimente incluir o domínio no usuário, ex:

```
$dados = array('host' => 'localhost', 'usuario@dominio.com' => 'teste', 'senha' => '123456');
```

se mesmo assim ainda tiver problemas experimente adicionar ao seu código:

```
ftp_pasv($conn,true);
```

Este comando muda o modo passivo em on ou off. No modo passivo, as conexões de dados são iniciadas pelo cliente, ao invés do servidor. Pode ser necessário se o cliente estiver atrás de um firewall.

Note que `ftp_pasv()` pode somente ser chamada depois do login ter sido feito com sucesso, caso contrário irá falhar.

Comment: o ftp_pasv() me retorna true, o ftp_nlist() me mostra apenas o diretorio root e o ftp_rawlist() me retorna vazio.

Comment: como criou o utilizador, via cpanel?
tem outros directórios ou ficheiros dentro da pasta do user?
ja testou com os mesmos dados se consegue ver os ficheiros num cliente de ftp?

Comment: se eu acessar o ftp pelo terminal com o mesmo usuario consigo listar

Comment: mas é um ftp local ou num webhost?

Comment: Se trata de um FTP local

Comment: não sera um problema de permissões?

Comment: No php ? por que no terminal funciona.